# Род слова "киви"?

Tags: существительные

Какой род у слова "киви" по последним учебникам?

Comment: Почему по учебникам? Словари не подойдут? И какие из них считать "последними"?

Answer (score 4):

Русский орфографический словарь Российской академии наук.
Отв. ред. В. В. Лопатин.
© Электронная версия, «ГРАМОТА.РУ», 2001–2007.

**Киви , нескл., м. и с. род (дерево и плод его).**

**Реально  в текстах можно встретить мужской и средний род**: фрукт - **м. род.** для родового названия, киви ― **ср. род** для несклоняемого существительного.

С точки зрения ботаники, плод киви ― это ягода, но его часто считают фруктом.

Примеры:

А я ела одно киви натощак с утра… а вечером стакан кефира… Понять, что киви спелый можно, понюхав фрукт...Твердый киви может дозревать в домашних условиях.